# How to set localstorage item back to null.

Tags: javascript, html, null, local-storage

I'm using a system to alert users when a major update has happened to a site, and I do it with LocalStorage, when I made the system, I made the system check if tip was "null", then set "tip" to true when they got the alert. Now, I would like to set the 'tip' localstorage back to null, and use "tip2" instead.

Would I do this? localStorage.setItem('tip', 'null');

Answer (score 38):

`localStorage.removeItem('tip')` if you are aiming to remove the key

`localStorage.setItem('tip', 'null')` if you just want to set it to the string "null"

Comment: or `localStorage.tip = 'null'`

Comment: Will this localStorage.removeItem('tip') work if I need to check on another part of my site for this: if(tip==null){

Comment: You should use `localStorage.getItem('tip') === null` to check if it exists.

Comment: @MichaelTheriot You forgot to add JSON.parse. Like so: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tip')) === null`

Comment: @williamle8300 You can use localStorage to store any type of serializable data by converting to JSON and back, but it's ultimately just a key-value store for strings. Also, `JSON.parse(null) === null`.

Comment: @MichaelTheriot Yea I agree it's a matter of style. Even though it's not part of the localStorage spec to have any notion of JSON, but in my opinion it's a web technology so I've always enforced this for getting/setting from localStorage: 1) `localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))` 2) `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))`. This is just my opinion, and you're probably right I shouldn't be imposing this, but I think it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Please consider not setting the value to a string “null”.  I’ve updated my answer here to try and explain more clearly the reason for this recommendation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015689/700206  Of course, I respect that Michael’s answer has more votes, it’s our privilege on SO to be able to choose from multiple approaches.

Comment: My answer was meant to illustrate that he was setting the value to the string "null" rather than actually removing the item, not to advocate for it. Also, there is a pattern to store serialized values other than strings in local storage via `JSON.stringify` and using `JSON.parse` on retrieval. In this pattern storing a `null` value would in fact store it as the string "null" and it would be correctly parsed on retrieval. Based on that, I do not see an issue discovering a string value "null" in local storage (even if redundant), since it might be intended by design.

Answer (score 26):

#### There is no way to set a localStorage item to have a value of null. Use remove instead.

Any localStorage item either has a string value, or it does not exist. No other type is possible, therefore no variation of null is possible either.

The confusing part is that as you noticed in your example, if you call localStorage.getItem('tip') and it does not exist, you’ll see a null return value in the debugger or when attempting to display the value.

As unintuitive as this is, it doesn’t mean a local storage item actually exists with a value of null. It really means the item 'tip' does not exist at all. There is not even a single internal trace anywhere of anything related to the key ‘tip’.

For an item that does exist, if you are trying to set the item "back to null" (which is impossible), what you should be doing instead is to **remove** the item.

In your example, this will cause you see the return value displayed as null again, like when you first called localStorage.getItem('tip'), even though it’s not null, it just doesn’t exist at all. To do that you can remove the item as described below.

Just remember all you ever need is **get**, **set**, and **remove**.

`localStorage.getItem('tip')`                                  // Get item value
`localStorage.setItem('tip','cool stuff')`          // Set item value
`localStorage.removeItem('tip')`                         // Remove item
    `if (localStorage.getItem('tip') === null)`  // Check if item exists

Technically, @Michael Theriot‘s answer was suggesting to set the item tip to a string value of "null". That’s not much different that setting it to “dog”, in that neither one of them is actually a system recognized null value.

I’m guessing that’s not what you meant, however even if it were, I would tend to advise against the practice because it can become confusing to others maintaining your code.